# Given two equal objects, filter only the differences

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have two different objects

```
let obj1 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "2",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "4"
}

let obj2 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "3",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "5"
}
```

I need a the differences in a new object that will depend on obj2

```
result = { "value2":"3" , "value4" : "5" }
```

The case can be too , that `obj1 === undefined`
In that case, I need all the values from obj2

Currently I have

```
let result = {}
let singleChange = false

for (const i of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    if (obj1 && obj1[i[0]] !== i[1]) {
      result [i[0]] = i[1];
      singleChange = true
    } else if(!singleChange) {
      result = obj2;
    }
  }
```

But it doesnt really sem to work properly all the times. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modern version with entries and fromEntries:

```js
let obj1 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "2",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "4"
}

let obj2 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "3",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "5"
}

let obj3 = undefined;

function objIntersection(o1, o2) {
  const filteredArray = Object.entries(o2)
  .filter(([k,v]) => o1?.[k] !== v);

  return Object.fromEntries(filteredArray);
}

console.log(objIntersection(obj1, obj2));
console.log(objIntersection(obj3, obj2));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obj1 = {
  value1: '1',
  value2: '2',
  value3: '3',
  value4: '4',
};

const obj2 = {
  value1: '1',
  value2: '3',
  value3: '3',
  value4: '5',
};
// find only the values that are different
const diff = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const obj3 = {};
  for (const key in obj1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      obj3[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  }
  return obj3;
}
console.log(diff(obj1, obj2));
```

Comment: u should take into account the undefined case as well

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries of the second object and filter with the first one.

```js
const
    getDifference = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(b)
        .filter(([k, v]) => a[k] !== v)
    ),
    obj1 = { value1 : "1", value2 : "2", value3 : "3", value4 : "4" },
    obj2 = { value1 : "1", value2 : "3", value3 : "3", value4 : "5" },
    result = getDifference(obj1, obj2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Fails if obj1 is undefined. But nice trick with the parameters in filter.

Comment: It still would fail with null. I think the only null-safe solution is `.filter(([k, v]) => a?.[k] !== v)`.

Comment: @Christian, no. the function expects two objects. if you have somthing different, then and  sanity check is needed in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with using an external package, Lodash has a good tool for this: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy

```
const { pickBy } = require('lodash');

const obj1 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "2",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "4"
}

const obj2 = {
  "value1" : "1",
  "value2" : "3",
  "value3" : "3",
  "value4" : "5"
}

const result = pickBy(obj2, (_, k) => obj2[k] !== obj1[k]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution with the reduce property.

```js
let obj1 = {
  value1: "1",
  value2: "2",
  value3: "3",
  value4: "4"
};

let obj2 = {
  value1: "1",
  value2: "3",
  value3: "3",
  value4: "5"
};

function findDiff(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.keys({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }).reduce(
    (prev, key) => ({
      ...prev,
      ...(obj1[key] !== obj2[key] && { [key]: obj2[key] || obj1[key] })
    }),
    {}
  );
}

console.log(findDiff(obj1, obj2));
```

Additional my code works if some object have more properties than other.

```js
let obj1 = { value1: "1", value2: "2", value3: "3" };
let obj2 = { ...obj1, value2: "3", value4: "13" };

function findDiff(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.keys({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }).reduce(
    (prev, key) => ({
      ...prev,
      ...(obj1[key] !== obj2[key] && { [key]: obj2[key] || obj1[key] })
    }),
    {}
  );
}

console.log(findDiff(obj1, obj2));
```